# jQuery conditional that checks the class and if it contains that class it executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working with wordpress and I have to display a menu based on a product category but it goes by term and there is no way for me to add a class. So I have term-maincat-subcat as the class and the subcat changes depending on where your at but the main cat stays the same as it is the brand. I was looking into the jQuery wildcards and there is a way to select an element with a certain string in a class. How would I go about running a conditional to check if it has that string in the class. Here's what I've got...

```
if($('body').is('body[class~="brand"]')) {
   $('.brand-cat-nav').show();
}
```

The above doesn't seems to work and like I said, unfortunately, there is no way of adding a straight "brand" class to it to make this a little easier with being able to just use .hasClass(). Any suggestions?

PS: the class that it's outputting to the body is some thing to likes of "term-maincat-subcat".

Comment: I may be wrong, but is it really that necessary to use some compound class strings - and not just several different classes, covering various aspects of an element? Class is not an ID, after all, it may not be unique.

Comment: For example, what's so wrong with `<div class="term tshirt blue">` and so right with `<div class="term-tshirt-blue">`? )

Comment: It's what the plugin is outputting. I agree, it is rather annoying and unnecessary. Your later suggestion would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if( $('body').filter("[class^='brand']").length )​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ {
    // body has class starting with 'brand'
}
```

This filters the `body` with a class name that starts with 'brand'.

If you want to test if `body` has a class *containing* 'brand' use `class*="brand"` as filter instead.

Answer (score 3):

Class is really easy to check:

```
if ($('body').is('.brand')) { ... }
```

or:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('brand')) { ... }
```

*edit* — if you mean that you want to find out if a string is *part* of a class, then that's going to require you going to the "className" property and checking with a regex:

```
if (/brand/.test($('body').prop('className'))) { ... }
```

If it's not always "brand", then you can make a regular expression from a string:

```
function whatever( someClassFragment ) {
  if (new RegExp(someClassFragment).test($('body').prop('className')) { ... }
```

If the string might have non-alpha characters in it then you'd have to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The issue I'm having is the class changes when you go into every subcategory. The main category is the same so for example I might be checking out t-shirts and it may be "term-tshirt", but then if i want to look at blue shirts it would be "term-tshirt-blue", but i want the tshirt navigation to show on every page that contains something about tshirts. If that make any sense, haha!

Comment: @DavidPoninski ok well I've updated the answer. The point is that you'll have to examine the "className" property with your own code, using a regular expression or something.

Comment: Or, rather than the regex, there's always `$('body').prop('className').indexOf("brand") !== -1`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder definitely - I'm a regex addict so I go there first but "indexOf" is fine too (does it exist on antique versions of IE or am I thinking of something else?)

Comment: @Pointy: You're thinking of `Array#indexOf`. `String#indexOf` is fine. :-)